# In editor trumbowyg , replace div tag with p tag

Tags: angular, angular6, trumbowyg

trumbowyg  rich text editor adds p tag on each line break, need to replace p tag with div tag.

setting property 'semantic': false on initialization does not seem to be working

```
<trumbowyg [initialContent]="resolutionTemplateContent" [options]="options1">
</trumbowyg>

options1 = { removeformatPasted: true,
    semantic : false }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to tamper with cleanpaste.js file. In that file all the html tag replacement is done in `cleanIt` function. There you can stop the replace

tag with  tag